# Best GPU to get for encoding / decoding multiple video streams and files?

Tags: linux, freebsd, ffmpeg, nvidia, gpu

I need to encode / decode multiple videos (both live and pre-recorded video files) at the same time but I'm not sure which GPU to get. I'll be using ffmpeg for the video manipulation.

Ideally I'd like to keep costs down because I'm still in the early phase so I'm not sure what the load will be on the server. I've been looking at various Nvidia cards but they aren't explicit about the video processing abilities of each card.

Linux or FreeBSD support is required.

Answer (score 1):

Do your own performance testing. An enormous number of variables affects the actual real world performance of things. And at best a recommendation would be a snapshot that gets out of date, GPUs change relatively quickly.

Acquire each candidate. Put them through their paces on the actual workload.

A decent vendor would have a return policy that takes back the rejects that don't work for you. Failing that, find out how your organization would sell off or write off used GPUs.